# Should our domain name end with .edu ?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure what the status of the discussion is on our domain name.  I propose that it have a .edu extension.  See my [blog post](http://ambergis.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/crowdsourcing-the-certification-process/) for reasons why.

Comment: Interesting blog post!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.edu domains were *intended* use as a name space for educational institutions.

In practice, its primary use is for universities.

The top-level domain is now officially restricted to "accredited post-secondary institutions and organizations that are accredited by nationally recognized accrediting agencies." ([citation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.edu)).

Stack Exchange does not qualify nor is it intended to meet any of those criteria.

Comment: Oh well,  to paraphrase John Belushi ... "seven months of stackexchange down the drain!"

Answer (score 2):

Why not .org? It's a minor difference, but calling it .com seems to diminish the community side of things, and suggest that it is purely a commercial endeavor.

Comment: It is a commercial endeavor: "... investors who believed in our mission, so we were able to raise enough money to make Stack Exchange absolutely free. (The details of that investment are not quite ready to be announced, but we’ll let you know as soon as they are)." http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/  In other words, se is kinda like http://www.phoenix.edu, but not accredited.

Comment: I don't disagree that it is a commercial endeavor, but it seems like it is not entirely commercial. The site objective seems to be more about sharing information, with the consequence of making money; rather than making money for its own sake.

Comment: There are a lot of commercial backed .org sites, especially from open source companies with parallel commerical and free product lines. In our case I think .org is applicable, as the value of the site, the community and it's content, is commercial free.